# ModuleNotFoundError When executing Python command inside bash script

Tags: python, bash, pycharm

The script runs fine from pycharm but can't see my my lib 
-> site-packages when ran as a shell script. I've set my `PYTHONPATH` variable and added it to `path` as `%PYTHONPATH%` but no luck. I've checked bashrc and can't see the environment variable being overwritten. Maybe my structure is incorrect?

```
 -lib
  - site-packages
 -scripts
 -src
  - monroes_events.py

**Error:**
(venv) C:\Users\James\repos\web_scraper\src>bash web_scraper_setup.sh
python3 Monroes_Scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Monroes_Scraper.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `pandas` module using `pip install pandas` which is required to run the `Monroes_Scraper.py`
You can find more detail [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html)

Comment: Pandas is installed and when Monroes_Scraper.py is ran in pycharm it works fine, it's only when running from a terminal as: `#!/bin/bash  

python3 "Monroes_Scraper.py"` that it can't see my lib folder with my modules.

Comment: @curley633 Did you install```pandas ```in the same virtual environment?

Comment: I think they were indeed installed in a different virtual environment, I reinstalled the Interpreter and all the modules in the same virtual environment and it works now from a gitbash terminal